# Equation translation: $V=\{f\in C^0([0,1]);\ f(0)=f(1)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What does this equation say in English? More specifically, what does $C^0([0,1])$ mean?

$V=\{f\in C^0([0,1]);\ f(0)=f(1)=0\}$

If it helps, this is a set that I need to prove whether or not is a vector space.

EDIT: Okay, I just read something that says,

> Here we denote the set of all continuous functions on $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ by $C^0(I)$.

However, I'm still confused by what it means to say, $C^0([0,1])$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C^0([0,1])$ represents the set of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$. Therefore, $V$ is the set of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$ vanishing at the endpoints. For example, the functions $|x-\frac{1}{2}|-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ both belong to $V$.

More generally, the notation $C^n(A)$ represents the set of all $n$-times continuously differentiable functions on $A$.

Answer (score 2):

In words, I would write
$$V=\{f\in C^0([0,1]);\ f(0)=f(1)=0\}$$
as

> $V$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ (i.e. all $f$ in $C^0([0,1])$) such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$.

This set is indeed a vector space under the usual addition/scalar multiplication of functions.